# Why can't I fetch wikipedia pages with LWP::Simple?

Tags: perl, wikipedia, lwp

I'm trying to fetch Wikipedia pages using [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl), but they're not coming back. This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

print get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow");
```

doesn't print anything. But if I use some other webpage, say `http://www.google.com`, it works fine.

Is there some other name that I should be using to refer to Wikipedia pages?

What could be going on here?

Comment: Note you're getting a "403 Forbidden" error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently Wikipedia blocks LWP::Simple requests: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=695886

The following works instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->get($url);

print $res->content;
```

Comment: I am getting error **500 Can't connect to en.wikipedia.org:443** for the given wiki URL, however for stackoverflow home page http://stackoverflow.com, it gives 403.
I've added `$ua->agent("WikiBot/0.1");` before calling `get` method, this worked cool for many sites including stackoverflow. But it still gives error on wiki page, same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Added `$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });
` and this error **500 Can't connect to en.wikipedia.org:443** got fixed. It may help someone else.

Answer (score 11):

You can also just set the UA on the LWP::Simple module - just import the $ua variable, and it'll allow you to modify the underlying UserAgent:

```
use LWP::Simple qw/get $ua/;
$ua->agent("WikiBot/0.1");
print get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow");
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem using `LWP:RobotUA` instead of `LWP::UserAgent`. You can read the document below. There are not much differences you should modify.

http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch12_02.htm

Answer (score 5):

Because Wikipedia is blocking the HTTP user-agent string used by LWP::Simple.

You will get a "403 Forbidden"-response if you try using it.

Try the LWP::UserAgent module to work around this, setting the agent-attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Also see the Mediawiki related CPAN modules - these are designed to hit Mediawiki sites (of which wikipedia is one) and might give you more bells and whistles than simple LWP.

http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/search?query=Mediawiki&mode=dist