# Perl doesn't load Wikipedia pages?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I fetch wikipedia pages with LWP::Simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546/why-cant-i-fetch-wikipedia-pages-with-lwpsimple)

First of all I would like to say I have no experience at all at Perl. In fact, I only started studying it today.

However, I came across a strange problem which I can't seem to solve it or look for a solution online. My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $html = get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl") or die "ERROR";
  print $html;
```

For some reason, this throws "ERROR" at me in every attempt of running the application. Strangely enough, if I replace the Wikipedia article with "http://www.google.com" or practically anything else, it works rather well.

What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3690671

Comment: I'm very sorry. I don't know how I didn't see it. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia refuses to answer anonymous callers. Set your user agent properly. Also, be aware that they dislike programmatic requests; there is an [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) for that, and you can also [download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) the whole database.